# Datagridview : DataGridViewImageColumn displays a red cross

Tags: c#, datagridview

I have a datagridview fed by a datatabe to which I have added an extra dataGridViewImageColumn. However, instead of displaying the correct flag (picture) in the added column, a red cross appears.

I have googled the entire afternoon for this problem, still wondering what I am doing wrong here. Any idea?

Thanks in advance for your help.

```
    private void displayMeteoCities()
    {
        DataTable l_Table = null;
        ClsCountriesFactory l_Countries = null;
        DataGridViewImageColumn l_ImageColumn = null;
        Bitmap l_Flag = null;
        string l_Country = string.Empty;

        try
        {
            this.m_Meteo_Cities = new ClsMeteoCitiesFactory();
            this.m_Meteo_Cities.getMeteoCities();
            l_Table = ClsDomoosManagerCore.CreateDataTable(this.m_Meteo_Cities.Meteo_Cities);
            this.dgr_Meteo_Cities.DataSource = l_Table;


            l_ImageColumn = new DataGridViewImageColumn();
            // l_ImageColumn.DisplayIndex = 0;
            l_ImageColumn.Width = 50;
            l_ImageColumn.Name = "Country_flag";
            //l_ImageColumn.SortMode = DataGridViewColumnSortMode.NotSortable;
            this.dgr_Meteo_Cities.Columns.Add(l_ImageColumn);

            l_Countries = new ClsCountriesFactory();
            l_Countries.loadCountryFlags();

            this.dgr_Meteo_Cities.RowsDefaultCellStyle.BackColor = Color.Moccasin;
            this.dgr_Meteo_Cities.AlternatingRowsDefaultCellStyle.BackColor = Color.GreenYellow;

            for (int i = 0; i < this.dgr_Meteo_Cities.Rows.Count; i++)
            {
                l_Country = Convert.ToString(this.dgr_Meteo_Cities["iso_country", i].Value);
                l_Flag = l_Countries.Flags[l_Country];
                this.dgr_Meteo_Cities[7, i].Value = l_Flag;
            }

        }
        catch (Exception exc)
        {
            ClsErrorManager.manageException(exc);
        }
        finally
        {
            l_Table = null;
            l_Flag = null;
        }
}
```

Comment: A red cross (assuming it's a red X) meaning that the image can't be found. Check the path of where your image is.

Comment: I have checked that - thanks

Comment: So, did that fix it?

Comment: No, it didn't ... I'm 100% sure of my path. All the images are in my resources

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I know it's an old question, but in the hopes of solving someones frustration in the future...

Whilst I'd almost always recommend against fiddling with Controls Constructors when using the Designer, in this case it's the correct way of handling it. Find the image column (not the `DataGridView`) in the `InitializeComponent` routine, and add the below line, replacing `ImageColumn` with the name of your image column:

**VB.Net**

```
Me.ImageColumn.DefaultCellStyle.NullValue = Nothing
```

**C#**

```
{
    this.ImageColumn.DefaultCellStyle.NullValue = null;
}
```

Comment: Thank you very much @RazorKillBen, indeed your solution helped me a lot.
(Would appreciate if you could upvote my question, that would help people to realise that your solution is definitely very valid). Have a good day.

Comment: Wow, glad to hear it helped 3 years on! Have done so, best of luck.